# How do I pass a number to .hideRow()?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I got the following script from [@Mike Grace's website](http://geek.michaelgrace.org/2015/02/delete-a-row-in-google-spreadsheets-based-on-value-of-cell/):

```
// Deletes rows in the active spreadsheet that contain 'Yes' in column A
function readRows() { 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange(); 
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows(); 
  var values = rows.getValues(); 

  var rowsDeleted = 0; 
  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) { 
    var row = values[i];
    if (row[0] == 'Yes') { 
      sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
      rowsDeleted++; 
    } 
  } 
}
```

The script works well, but I would like to make a change to it, instead of calling `.deleteRow()` I want to use `.hideRow()` instead.

Because the `.hideRow()` method only accepts a range as far as I understand, I'm getting the following error:

[image: error message]

How do I modify this script so that it hides the row instead of deleting them?

Comment: It's not clear how you tried calling `hideRow` to get that error message - can you update your question with the code that you used to get that error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are different hideRow / s () methods, [one of them takes a row number as argument](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hideRows(Integer)).

your code can be simplified like this :

```
function hideRowsWithYes() { 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues(); 

  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) { 
    if (values[i][0] == 'Yes') { 
      sheet.hideRows(1+i);
    } 
  } 
}
```

As usual, autocomplete makes the job easier...

[image]

---

### Edit following comment :

to unhide row we don't have a simple method with row index so we need to define the range... code goes like this (`i` has a `+1` because values is an array that starts from 0 while `sheets` are indexed from 1)

```
function unHideRows() { 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues(); 
  var row;
  var maxCol = sheet.getMaxColumns();
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) { 
    if (values[i][0] == 'Yes') { 
      row = sheet.getRange(1+i, 1, 1, maxCol);
      sheet.unhideRow(row);
    } 
  } 
}
```

Comment: This is amazing, exactly how I want it.
Do you know how to undo it via a script? Like unhide it again, the same way you hide it with a script?

And also, what does (1 + i) do in the .hideRow() method?